# Listening to Room database insert with RXJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

I have a simple Android application with Room database and I am trying to react to an `@Insert` query with RxJava but I am unable to chain the calls correctly.

This is my view model method calling the insert:

```
fun insertTopic(): Single<Long> {
        val topic = Topic(null, topicText.value!!, difficulty.value!!, false)

        return Single.create<Long> { Observable.just(topicDao.insert(topic)) }
    }
```

And this is the code in my activity triggering the save action:

```
disposable.add(RxView.clicks(button_save)
            .flatMapSingle {
                viewModel.insertTopic()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError { Toast.makeText(this, "Error inserting topic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
            .subscribe { id ->
                // NOT INVOKED
                hideKeyboard()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Topic inserted. ID: $id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                this.finish
            })
```

When I click the button, the entity is saved but none of the subscribe code is invoked (no toast is shown). Could someone point out to me what am I doing wrong? I am fairly new to RX java.

Comment: did you try onNext()? might be able to solve the problem with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in incorrect usage of `Single.create`. There is no need in wrapping `topicDao.insert(topic)` into `Observable`. Moreover, you are implementing new Single manually, which means you must pass the result id to the `@NonNull SingleEmitter<T> emitter` argument. But there is no need in using `Single.create` here.

`Single.fromCallable` is exactly what you need:

```
fun insertTopic(): Single<Long> = Single.fromCallable {
    val topic = Topic(null, topicText.value!!, difficulty.value!!, false)
    return@fromCallable topicDao.insert(topic)
}
```

Please note, that I create `topic` object inside lambda so that it isn't captured in a closure. Also keep in mind that `fromCallable` [may throw](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) `UndeliverableException` if you unsubscribe from `Single` during the lambda code execution. It will probably never happen in your specific case, but you should understand [RxJava2 error handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling) design.